# How can I handle Document.BeginPage() Error in SkiaSharp.SKDocument,.Net maui

Tags: c#, android, ios, maui, skiasharp

The code complies and then on debugging, on the line of

```
document.BeginPage()
```

Debugging stops with no error shown.

Building mobile app, Am trying to create a pdf with a table of inventory count for particular date then share the pdf ,using skiasharp in .net maui.
Here is the code;

```
        public async Task<SKDocument> GenerateInventoryItemCountPdfAsync(DateTime date, List<Item> items, string pdfLogoPath, string pdfTitle) 
         { 
             var stream = new MemoryStream(); 
             using var document = SKDocument.CreatePdf(stream); 
  
             var pageSize = new SKSize(595, 842); 
             using var canvas = document.BeginPage((int)pageSize.Width, (int)pageSize.Height); 
  
             using (var logoBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(pdfLogoPath)) 
             { 
  
                 var logoRect = SKRect.Create(pageSize.Width / 2 - logoBitmap.Width / 2, 50, logoBitmap.Width, logoBitmap.Height); 
                 canvas.DrawBitmap(logoBitmap, logoRect); 
  
                 var titlePaint = new SKPaint 
                 { 
                     Typeface = SKTypeface.FromFamilyName("Arial", SKFontStyleWeight.Bold, SKFontStyleWidth.Normal, SKFontStyleSlant.Upright), 
                     TextSize = 24, 
                     IsAntialias = true, 
                     Color = SKColors.Black
```

Comment: If you put try..catch around all the code, with breakpoint in catch block, does an exception get caught?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I have tried it but still debugging stops at that line without throwing an exception.

Comment: I see in doc that the returned canvas is owned by the document (not by your calling method). Maybe try without `using` in front of `var canvas = ...`.

Comment: Did that too. It still failed.

Comment: Could that be conversion error? Can you try to set `document.BeginPage((int)(pageSize.Width), (int)(pageSize.Height)); ` If that doesn't work, please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link?